# How to post tweet (description and images) in twitter using API or JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript, api

I want to post description and images using twitter API or JavaScript so what the code for that... Please help or any solution for that.

I have use the following code.

```
include('tmhOAuth.php');
include('tmhUtilities.php');

$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
  'consumer_key'    => '2gfF75xRSwnJDgfuwXBUGj59kA',
  'consumer_secret' => 'snGgVlYdVfgOeTVl8aQYG5BQRyEbgxqfgu9B9zTpRomIUh58',
  'user_token'      => '148xf1479562-RYq76XIfgogfhjttdu0kLlWwQwEfgEM8wlRDMX44rUFPP',
  'user_secret'     => 'I7saxfu751zzMnWChgffA0VAiRQIdf2JFwTMLragf6MK4aF8pjbg',
));

  $image = 'Chrysanthemum.jpg';
  $code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', 'https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json',
  array(
    'media[]'  => "@{$image}",
        "status"   => "Is this working now?"
       ),
       true, // use auth
       true  // multipart
  );
  if ($code == 200) {
    tmhUtilities::pr(json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response']));
  } else {
    tmhUtilities::pr($tmhOAuth->response['response']);
  }
```

But , i have got this error:
JSON RESPONSE:

```
{
errors: [
    {
        message: "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.",
        code: 68
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: What is unclear about that error message?

Comment: I guess you should use the 1.1 API  
https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-is-retired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should use the 1.1 API 
http://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-is-retired

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media

```
Resource URL
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json
```

Comment: @kalpesh how did u post can u share ur working sample?

Comment: @Antouank just post your code please

Comment: This method is deprecated now.