# Tweeting an image using Twitter API

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

As a part of the application. I want users to share the image generated using the app with some text of their choice.

I went on to use a Twitter Library [twitteroauth](https://github.com/natefanaro/twitteroauth) by natefanaro which supports to tweet images with text via Twitter API.

https://github.com/natefanaro/twitteroauth

According to the Library one can send a tweet with text by the method below.

```
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' =>"Test Tweet"));
```

When i tried with a post a tweet along with a image and text. It ain't works.Here's the code to post image with some text.

```
$connection->post('statuses/update_with_media', array('status' => 'Test Tweet with Img from  App', 'media[]'=>'img03.jpg'));
```

PS: All i need is to let the users of the app share the image to their twitter timeline. Help me if there's a better method to do the same.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post more details and more code snippets, that would be much better to help you out.

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash Thank you. I have made the update. Could you look at it now.

Comment: Check the answers in this SOF question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184305/how-to-post-tweet-descrition-and-images-in-twitter-using-api-or-javascript , also you need to properly debug your code, the way you are posting question details are pretty minimal which prevents people to lend you a hand of help.

Comment: Thank you again.I am looking for multiple user oAuth. But the method you suggested seems it is for single user oAuth. And i shared only the specific line of code which i felt i made some mistake. Rest of the code comes with the library.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$connection->post('statuses/update_with_media', array('status' => 'Test Tweet with Img from  App', 'media[]'=>'img03.jpg'));
```

to:

```
$connection->upload('statuses/update_with_media', array('status' => 'Test Tweet with Img from  App', 'media[]'=>'img03.jpg'));
```

Notice the change from "post" to "upload"

Comment: This answer is correct. There was an issue with the documentation where the example for tweeting with an image used post() instead of upload. The docs have been updated in this commit https://github.com/natefanaro/twitteroauth/commit/05bf4cc056a46d9e568a15c9c06a932bc174f10b